# stop files from truncating Java?

Tags: java, file

here is my code

```
try {
        fstream = new FileWriter("/Applications/AirDrop/contacts.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

          out.write(stringToInsert);

        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

now everytime I try to call this method (this is code is in a method called writeToFile with a string parameter) the string which

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the [two-argument constructor of `FileWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29):

```
fstream = new FileWriter("/Applications/AirDrop/contacts.txt", true);
```

Better yet: don't use `FileWriter` at all, because it always uses the platform default encoding, which is not usually a good idea! Instead you should explicitly specify which encoding to use (UTF-8 is usually a good default, if you don't know what else to chose):

```
fstream = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/Applications/AirDrop/contacts.txt", true), "UTF-8");
```

Another hint: it is pretty likely that constantly opening and closing the file is not the best idea: You should usually open the file once for writing, write everything you need to write to it and *then* close it.

Comment: thanks for that if I don't close nothing gets written in the file for some reason

Comment: @Tushar: If you need the data to be written to the file *before* it is closed (that's usually just necessary for log files or similar things), then you need to call `flush()`. Note that I didn't say you should *never* close the file. I just said you should open and close the file *once*.